# R - Find the sum for the lagging record and add another column to current value iteratively

Tags: r, dataframe

So my dataframe is structured like so:

| x | s |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 0 |
| 13 | 0 |
| -3 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| -4 | 0 |

for each row in s, I would like to take the lag(s), add it to column x, then set it to the value of s.

my output data would therefore look like:

| x | s |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 0 |
| 13 | 13 |
| -3 | 10 |
| 2 | 12 |
| -4 | 8 |

I tried the following function, but after fiddling I was only able to get all NA's or all 0's:

```
mydata$s = lag(mydata$s)+mydata$x
```

Note - if it helps, I can remove the first row.

Comment: `transform(df, s = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()` to perform the job, and also replace `NA` with 0 during the calculation (without changing your original dataset).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(s = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)))

   x  s
1 NA  0
2 13 13
3 -3 10
4  2 12
5 -4  8
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.
Set up:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(NA, 13, -3, 2, -4), s = c(0, 13, 10, 12, 8) )
mydata$s <- lag(mydata$s)+mydata$x
```

Gives:

```
mydata
   x  s
1 NA NA
2 13 13
3 -3 10
4  2 12
5 -4  8
```

The difference is my first s is NA. That should be expected as the first x is NA.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
mydata$s <- c(mydata$x[1], cumsum(mydata$x[-1]))
```

Data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(NA, 13, -3, 2, -4))
```

Comment: this gives me an index error